# Screen goes blank when installing Ubuntu on Asus Zenbook UX31A

Tags: 12.04, installation, asus, ultrabook

I have a problem installing any Ubuntu distribution (12.04, 12.10, 13.04) on my Asus Zenbook UX31A-C4046H. When I tried with the live USB boot, selecting install led  to a blank screen. I have Intel HD Graphics 4000. Is this a problem with the graphics card? What could I do?

I found the below website, tried to edit grub - replace splash by nomodeset then push F10, still no result.

http://webent.altervista.org/2012/09/16/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-12-04-or-newer-on-the-zenbook-ux32vd/

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue. I had to enable CSM in the bios. However, it'll be grayed out if you started the PC without the live usb already connected. So, full tutorial that worked for me:

1. [Dissable FastStartup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html).
2. Dissable FastBoot. To do this, you need to **restart** windows 8. You cannot turn it off/on manually, since the new "turn off" is actually hibernate. Make sure that you connect the live usb before restarting it.
3. Enable CSM in the boot menu.
4. Select your usb as main boot device.
5. Proceed as normally.

I added some extra info back in the [Ubuntu Asus Zenbook Prime wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime).

Answer (score 0):

I found it finally, the below link helped a lot!

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Summary:

In your BIOS,

1/ disable QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT).

2/ If you have Windows8, also disable FastStartup.

Now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete video about this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbxrSaclKRc

In your case, you just have to add the "dis_ucode_ldr" parameter to the boot commands, before booting.

Summary of the fix:

add the boot parameter: dis_ucode_ldr to /etc/default/grub
update-grub
More info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620

What actually is a proper fix, is to update your firmware. In the last version this is no longer an issue.